# Problem with auto IK, some bones turned stiff (Auto IK doesn't work)

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

First time working with armatures and IK, I had a rig working and somehow I did something that broke it. I'm using the Auto IK option for it.

It's a 2D spider (don't mind the leg count) and each leg segment is a separate object.

This link has a video of it working and one of it not working
https://imgur.com/a/6oDkFQE

To describe it, it's as if the first 2 leg segments had their rotation locked, and the 3rd one didn't, but I can't find what's locking it, if that's actually what's happening.

As far as I can tell, rotation is not locked in:

- The menu that appears when you press N
- The Bone Properties tab

If you have any idea what might be causing it, I'd appreciate it.

The blend file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've selected the bone in *Pose* mode, press <kbd>G</kbd> and use the <kbd>MMB</kbd> to choose the length of the auto IK chain so that it affects more or less bones, the length is displayed at the top left of your 3D view:

[image]

Comment: Got it, many thanks